# Iterator writing to File.txt Java

Tags: java

Here  is my issue: I need to write the Interator to the file "random.txt" I am able to see all the data. The data is Store where suppose to, I can see it with the System.out.print but my file is in blank. I am able to create the file but not to writer to it.

I am reading a file from my comp. store in the Treemap and trying to write to the text file. ( I am able to doit with Array with not problem) But this Map with Iterator is bouncing my head.

If some one can help me a litter I will appreciated.

I need to use the TreeMap and the Iterator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Map<String, String> Store = new TreeMap<>();

    Scanner text=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter file:  ");


    //C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Fruits\fruits.txt           

    String rap=text.next();

    File into = new File(rap);

    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(into)) {                

        while (in.hasNext()){
            String name=in.next();
            String fruta = in.next();
            Integer num= Integer.parseInt(in.next());
            System.out.println(fruta+"\t"+name+"\t"+num);

            if (Store.containsKey(fruta)){
                Store.put(name,Store.get(name)+fruta );
            }
            else{
                Store.put(name,fruta);
            }
        }

        in.close();

    }                                                                

    System.out.println();

    // insert data to store MAP 
    Set top=Store.entrySet();
    Iterator it = top.iterator();  

    // debugging 

    System.out.println(top);

    // Creating file???????
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("random.txt");  

    //identify File to be write?????? 
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    //iterator Loop       
    while(it.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String key = (String)m.getKey();
        String value = (String)m.getValue();

        //writing to file?????
        out.write("\t "+key+"\t "+value);

        // debugging 
        System.out.println(key +"\t"+ value);
    }       

    System.out.println("File created successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `while` loop (the one writing to file) is finished, do:

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

**Short explanation:** `BufferedWriter` buffers in memory what you write. It doesn't immediately write to file when you call the `write` method. Once the while loop is finished and the data to write to file is prepared in buffer memory, you should call `flush` to do the *actual* writing to hard disk. And finally you should always `close` the BufferedWriter that will no longer be used, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Perfect Thank you so much. That was 72 hour of head aid for 2 lines of code.

Comment: Hahaha... Don't you wish your IDE warned you "Hey dude, you're not flushing and closing!"? Glad I could help :)